# Email not sent mdaemon configuration done but mailnot sent through and not getting error php file

Tags: php, mysql, css, html, email

Email not sent MDaemon configuration done but mailnot sent through and not getting error php file or any other configuration required Ihave done MDeamoen Config done but the mail not sent 
anything more required I am new in php and MDeamon
**Code :**

```
    // smtp domain name
    ini_set("SMTP","48.48.48.250");

    //sendmail path for sending email
    ini_set("sendmail_path", "M:\MDaemon\App\MDaemon.exe\ -t -i");

    // Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.

    ini_set("smtp_port","25");

    // Please specify the return address to use

    ini_set('sendmail_from', 'ticketing@solinfinite.com');





    // multiple recipients
    $to  = 'mukeshbpatidar@gmail.com' . ', '; // note the comma
    $to .= 'hr@solinfinite.com';

    // subject
    $subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

    // message
    $message = '
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: Mukesh  <mukesh@solinfinite.com>, Kelly <hr@solinfinite.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <ticketing@solinfinite.com>' . "\r\n";


    // Mail it
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
        {
        echo 'Email sent successfully!';
    }
     else 
     {

       die('Failure: Email was not sent!');

     }

  /* Code running properly and sent msg successfully but mail not sent if any idea about MDeamon or I have to other Configuration done  on localhost that should be run properly and send mail success *?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have miss configuration.

Please see official [blog](http://blogs.mdaemon.com/index.php/page/3/http://blogs.mdaemon.com/index.php/page/3/) here also see a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F80hWrp7duo)

Just try simple text email:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

If simple email working then you need to install PEAR package » PEAR::Mail_Mime.

> Note: If intending to send HTML or otherwise Complex mails, it is
>   recommended to use the PEAR package » [PEAR::Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime).

Comment: When i send mail from localhost than mail sent properly but when use MDaemon path than mail not sent even message show me mail sent successfully